# Image with Url like Filename Cannot be Loaded by the browser

Tags: html, image

In our app, if a user wants to include an image, he or she will have to place the link to the image url.

What happens on the backend is that the image is retrieved and placed to file and then resized

I have an image with a file name that looks like this:

```
images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbay4DeeD7J1OsJH7yG3mq3_qR6CoXUFK3n87zh4ffuPbsouMr_128.png
```

Which is referenced in html like so:

```
<img src="/applicationfiles/1/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbay4DeeD7J1OsJH7yG3mq3_qR6CoXUFK3n87zh4ffuPbsouMr_128.png">
```

I have since then tried to change how images are saved to file in terms of their names since a file name like the above does not load in the browser. Other simpler file names like picture.png load okay though.

My question now is why can't the browser load filenames that look like urls?

Comment: are you sure from the name of the image that it's saved like this ? 
this is because files names in windows File systems can't accept characters like " : "

Comment: @HadyElsahar I am using a unix box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL contains characters that needs to be encoded. 
Only `images` will be used as filename, the rest(after ? ) will be the QUERY-STRING

It Should be:

```
images%3Fq%3Dtbn%3AANd9GcQbay4DeeD7J1OsJH7yG3mq3_qR6CoXUFK3n87zh4ffuPbsouMr_128.png
```

Comment: The slashes are the directory-separators, not a part of a directoryname/filename